# Equivalent concept of Java package in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm porting Java code to TypeScript. The Java code contains packages (each in its own folder). Typically, there were "many" (around 20) files in each package. This causes new TypeScript code to contain tens of individual file imports.

What would be the idiomatic TypeScript approach to reduce the number of imports?

- Have a single file per directory which includes everything in the package?
- Keep having many single file imports?

Comment: You can try [namespaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html)

Comment: Not the downvoter: not sure why you consider imports as a drawbacks, Java classes that use other classes also contain multiple imports at the beginning of each class file. Java packages group multiple classes into one physical boundary, in Typescript you'd get a similar result by compiling multiple *.ts files into a single javascript output. The output (as a single file) could be then linked into other "packages". As for [namespaces](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tXK50czRbdA&t=990s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *equivalent* concept is Namespaces

```
export namespace Foo {
  export class Bar {}
}
// other file
export namespace Foo {
  export class Baz {}
}
// compiles roughly to
export const Foo = {
   Bar: class Bar{},
   Baz: class Baz{},
}
```

What you want hovewer is probably making `index.ts` that reexports all the things from there:

```
// index.ts
export * from './bar.ts'
export { Baz } from './baz.ts'
// you don't need do reexport internals, leave them in their files
```

Then all you imports will be merged into a single one:

```
import { Bar, Baz } from 'foo'
// or
import * as Foo from 'foo';
Foo.Bar
```